# Python web scrape: dealing with user login popup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've seen posts and SO questions about user/login credentials for Python web scraping with beautiful soup and requests modules, and the solutions apply when the user/password box is built into the page.

But what about popups? Do I need a different approach?

I access from here:
https://csas.nbme.org/acpweb/servlet/AcpNbmeLogin?entryPoint=1001

which then opens the popup
https://csas.nbme.org/acpweb/servlet/userConnectInfo

Obviously, I have the login details. My first script attempts are not working.

So, are there some other modules or another approach I should pursue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a POST request first to send credentials to https://csas.nbme.org/acpweb/servlet/AcpUserMain with these informations :

```
dbconnect   y
entryPoint  1001
numblogon   0
password    yourpassword
username    yourusername
```

(I used the 'Network' tab of my Firefox console to see which request is done when the popup form is sent)

The server will send you cookies that you should keep - requests module do that well with [sessions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) :

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance

Then you can go to your desired page (using the same session object).

Code should look like this :

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post('https://csas.nbme.org/acpweb/servlet/AcpUserMain', data = {
        'dbconnect': 'y',
        'entryPoint': 1001,
        'numblogon': 0,
        'password': <yourpassword>,
        'username': <yourusername>,
    })

    r = s.get(<url to parse>)

#Use beautifoulsoup on r
```